# DataTemplate for MenuItem in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to define a `DataTemplate` for a `MenuItem`, the same way you can define `ContentTemplate` for a `ListBoxItem`. The problem is that I can't find the `ContentTemplate` property in the `MenuItem`'s class.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

            </DataTemplate>
        </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```